# Turn LED off and on using I2C, SPI or UART GPIO Pin

Tags: gpio, i2c, spi, uart

I have project requiring several simple LEDs and buttons, MORE that the number of ‘simple’ GPIO pins.  Can I turn the LED TOTALLY OFF and on using a IC2, SPI, or UART pin?  Can those pins be programed to respond to button pushes?

I did a test with such a pin, GPIO2 (Pin 3).  The result was when wired up initially, the LED was on.  When I ran a simple blink program, setting the LED to on would brighten the LED.  Setting the LED to off would dim, but not turn off, the LED.

I have a simple circuit: GPIO2 to LED to 1K resistor to ground.

Is it possible to fully turn off an LED connected to a IC2, SPI, or UART Pin?

I know this is similar this question.  However, that one does not address turning the LED completely off.

[Howto: Power on/off for GPIO3 (Pin 5)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54797/howto-power-on-off-for-gpio3-pin-5)

My code is

```
import time
import sys
from gpiozero import LED

green = LED(2)
green.off()
green.on()
time.sleep(3)
green.off()
```

Comment: The GPIO pins are not intended to be used to drive LED's directly. Instead use the GPIO to operate a transistor. There are many, many examples of this. Then you will be able to turn the LED off.

Comment: @Wendall: That's not strictly true. Many low-current LEDs can easily be driven from a GPIO pin (don't forget the series current-limiting resistor,

Comment: Seamus, I agree, but you won't get them to turn all the way OFF.

Answer (score 1):

All the GPIO can be used as "ordinary" inputs and outputs regardless of any special modes they might have.

There are a couple of things to note:

1. GPIO 2 and 3 (pins 3 and 5) have hard wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 fitted.
2. All the GPIO have weak internal pulls.  These may be set to up, down, or off.  GPIO 0-8 default to pull-ups, other GPIO to pull-downs.

These pulls will mean the GPIO have a default voltage of 3V3 for those with pull-ups and 0V for those with pull-downs.  This will affect connected circuitry (e.g. LEDs may light, a relay may operate, a motor might be set to run).

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not see how I can turn on an LED via GPIO2 using gpiozero library.
I understand that GPIO 0-8 default to pull-up.  Can that be overridden with gpiozero?
I know it can be overidden with RPi.GPIO

GPIO.setup(gpio_number, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

But how do  I make LED.off() in the gpiozero library turn off the led?  
Can I not do it using gpiozero?

My multi-meter tells the the off state is 2.56V and my on state is 3.19V

Comment: I answered the question as given. If you have a new question you need to post a new question.